# Appending new keys and values to a dictionary in a nested for loop without overwriting old entries

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have two data sources (`Subjects`) which are loaded via `np.loadtxt` into Python.

The loop `for ROI in ROIs` is nested in the loop `for Subject in Subjects`.

My aim is to append the computational results of `PLE = sp.stats.linregress(np.log(Ideal_frequency), np.log(Data))` of both subjects for each ROI into the dictionary. The code should append the result of PLE[0] of both subjects together into one list or array for each ROI.

My problem that I am unable to solve is that my code only appends the computational result `PLE[0]` for `Subject1` into `PLE_dict`. Consequently, `Subject2` is not included.

For example, printing the result via `PLE_dict` yields:

```
{1: [-0.9924575013746104],
 2: [-0.8905778114042852],
 3: [-1.0143346946069933],
.... # Cut the data here
```

The numbers 1 to 3 represent the first three ROIs, and the values in the square brackets the result of `PLE[0]`. Both is correct. However, I would also like to append the results of subject2 into the array or list for each ROI.

Here is my current code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import itertools as it
from scipy import stats


Ideal_frequency = np.loadtxt("/volumes/... .1D")

ROIs = it.chain(range(1,181), range(1001,1181)) # ROIs 1-180 and 1001-1180


Subjects = ["Subject1", "Subject2"]
      
PLE_dict = {}

for Subject in Subjects:
    for ROI in ROIs:
        
        Data = np.loadtxt(f"/volumes/seagate/{Subject}/G360_{ROI}_{Subject}.1D")
       
        PLE = sp.stats.linregress(np.log(Ideal_frequency), np.log(Data))
        
        if ROI not in PLE_dict:
            PLE_dict[ROI] = [PLE[0]]
        else:
            PLE_dict[ROI].append(PLE[0])

             
            

print(PLE_dict)
```

This screenshot maybe describes the problem better. Here is the output of `print(PLE_dict)`. It shows the results of `PLE[0]` for the last ROIs (one ROI per row). But these results are only for `subject1`. My aim is to add the results of `subject2` into the same rows for the single ROIs.

[image]

Comment: What you think is the reason, is not the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by:

```
        if ROI not in PLE_dict:
            PLE_dict[ROI] = [PLE[0]]
        else:
            PLE_dict[ROI].append(PLE[0])
```

Running

```
PLE_dict = {}

for Subject in range(2):
    for ROI in range(2):
        
        if ROI not in PLE_dict:
             PLE_dict[ROI] = [Subject*ROI]
        else:
             PLE_dict[ROI].append(Subject*ROI)

print(PLE_dict)
```

gives

```
{0: [0, 0], 1: [0, 1]}
```

Also

```
it.chain(range(1,181), range(1001,1181)) # ROIs 1
```

is an iterator and once iterated, it is empty and will not run a second time.
So either turn it into a list of put it directly into the loop.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this also only adds the results of subject1 into the dictionary, but the results for subject2 are missing (same problem as with my code).

Comment: So what is the error message?

Comment: No error occurs. The problem is that the code only computes the results for subject1, i.e., the first item in the ```Subjects``` list. The results for subject one are added into ```PLE_dict``` as intended. However, this step is not repeated for subject2, even though it is part of the list and for loop (```for Subject in Subjects```). The problem seems to be that the code simply stops after the computation for subject1, instead of adding the results of subject2 into the dictionary as well.

Comment: For your code this is clear, as during the second iteration the key is already found in the dictionary. So the condition evaluates to False.

Comment: Also ROI does not enter the calculation. So everything will be the same.

Comment: I updated the code as per your suggestion, but the problem remains the same. ROI is part of the nested for loop in ```Data```.

Comment: No, unless you put an f in front of your string.

Comment: Oh, yes. I forgot to include the f here on stackoverflow, but it was part of my script with the full paths. So the problem is not related to a missing f here.

Comment: What is the output with the current version?

Comment: The output of the current version is the same as shown in the screenshot above. This means that ```PLE``` is apparently only computed for the first item in the list (```Subject1```), and the results of ```Subject2```are not added into the dictionary.

Comment: Are you sure, you are essentially running this code?

Comment: Yes, 100%. I know that it seems strange, I am stuck with the code for hours. The problem does not appear to stem from ```ROI```,  since the ```PLE``` values are correctly computed and assigned to all ```ROIs``` for ```Subject1```. It appears that my code just ignores ```Subject2```. The data is OK. I can delete ```Subject1``` from the list, and then the code does the correct computations for ```Subject2```.

Comment: Well, if I am running this, I am getting the desired output.

Comment: In your case, you are getting two values (as output) per row when typing ```PLE_dict``` in the console after the computation, correct? For example, the last line would look something like this: ```1180: [-0.53553, -0.934343]}```. If that is the case for you, I really wonder what is going wrong on my computer.

Comment: This is exactly what I am getting. The code you are running is different from what you are showing

Comment: Ok, now I have an idea. The last line of ```Data = np.loadtxt``` is ```f{Subject}/360_{ROI}_{Subject}.1D").``` Could the problem stem from the fact that ```Subject```and ```ROI```are both part of the path? This is due to my data structure, but I am now wondering if that somehow confuses Python.

Comment: No, that is not the reason.

Comment: I just saw the edit in your answer. Adding the suggested lines of code yields an output like this for each ROI: ```1180: ['Subject1Subject1Subject1 ... ']}```where ```Subject1```is repeated by the overal number of ROIs, I think.

Comment: Sure, because that's just a placeholder for me to add something there. I don't have your data, nor does this depend on the data or the calculation or the filenames. Last try: COPY the code you are CURRENTLY really running.

Comment: Also, you don't seem to notice that I also changed the loops. They are only running over [0,1] in my case. You really need to check code more carefully.

Comment: Suggestion: run the very code I've been posting, see that it works as you intend and that it solves your problem. Then replace the iterators by your iterators and insert the calculation you actually want to calculate.

Comment: The paradigmatic example code that you showed under ```Running``` works. Please see my edited code in the initial post. Did I miss something in the code? The output remains the same as before.

Comment: But that screenshot can not be the output of the code you gave there or that I gave. The values of the dictionary are clearly lists, not floats. This is true irregardless of what you put for `PLE[0]`.

Comment: The files loaded into Python are 1D files (basically .txt files) that each consist of one column with 100 or more numerical values; one value per row. The PLE is a linear regression of these values against the frequency file that is loaded into Python too. The values shown make sense. The code shown is exactly the code that I use. I only cut the full paths to the files (the directories). I appreciate your help and I assure you that this updated code is the one used. It only produces the output for the first subject in the list, no matter what subject I put first.

Comment: The code given either appends an element to a list, or assigns a list to a dictionary value. Your screenshot can not be the output of your code. The content of your files or what calculation you are doing is not important. If it was, you would see an exception somewhere.

Comment: I just ran the code again in the original Python IDE (instead of in Spyder IDE). The result looks like this: ```{1: [-0.992457501374611], 2: [-0.8905778114042855], ... , 1179: [-0.4809151931081863], 1180: [-0.7839399005802057]}```. I shortended the output list so that the general structure of the output becomes clear. It produces a list for every ```ROI``` with one value for each, but the values only stem from ```Subject1```.  I have no clue what I am doing wrong. This is precisely the code shown in the updated initial post.

Comment: If you don't see the difference to your screenshot..

Comment: Irrespective of the precise code that I used back when I made the screenshot (and interchanged subject 1 against 2 for testing, hence the different values), the problem that subject2 (or a successive subject) are not added into the dictionary remains. The problem is not solved when using the original Python IDE (vs. Spyder IDE). I will have to figure out what is going wrong here.

Comment: Well, my answer solved the actual problem. You can see that when you replace `PLE[0]` by `[(Subject,ROI)]`

Comment: Sorry, can you put the expression for ROIs directly in the loop, IE without assigning it to a variable?

Comment: See my edited answer for the iterator issue

Comment: Thomas, moving ```ROIs = it.chain(range(1,181), range(1001,1181))``` into the for loop, more precisely right after ```for Subject in Subjects``` (before the ROI loop) solved the problem. Now, Python computes and loads the result for subject2, subject3, and so on into the dictionary ```PLE_dict``` side by side. Thank you for your patience with me.